# How can I format selected cells (column) to 9 digit number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro to change a selected column containing 7 digit numbers to 9 digits (2 leading zeros). I have no knowledge of vba. I am trying to learn but the terminology is so vast. In the meantime, I have been using code that I have found on the internet to suit my needs. For example, the code I use for the selection is as follows:

```
Sub SelectDn()

SelectDn Macro

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```

So I use this to select the data I want to format.

My colleagues at work do a lot of manual manipulation to their excel spreadsheets to create reports and I want to make the process easier for them. I know it's just a matter of right-clicking, `Format cells, Custom, 000000000` but would like to do it with less steps.

Is there a way to doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried this:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "000000000"
Selection.TextToColumns
```

I used the macro recorder and formatted the 7 digit number to 9 digit. The code that it generated was:

```
Sub Macro14()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "000000000"
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the macro again, I get a Compile error: Expected Function or variable and the word "Selection" in Selection.NumberFormat is highlighted. I would like the number to change from 9983743 to 009983743.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference a column to some cell with `EntireColumn`. This is where you want to apply your format so.....

```
Sub Digits()

    Selection.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "000000000"

End Sub
```

---

Also, `.Selection` is usually not the best way to refer to a range. Is there some other, more systematic, way you can refer to your target columns? If so, I would consider revising this to do so. Maybe `InputBox` or pre-code the columns where you expect this format to apply.

Comment: urdearboy, your Digits macro worked perfectly. Your recommendation on pre-coding the columns is something I plan to do for preformatted templates. I will look into InputBox as your suggest as well. Thank you very much for your help.